# Make a "Taxonomy Term" Appear in search field

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

What my requirement is to display taxonomy terms in search results when someone searches for anything related/similar to it. 
For example: I have a taxonomy ABC, and articles 1,2,3,4 related to it. So when somebody searches ABC, along with article 1,2,3,4, ABC should also be visible there.
I suppose i would have to edit the .tpl.php file of 'search display' and also add the required fields in the taxonomy fields(like image and description) which are required by the articles when searched.Where and how can i add fields in taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Views installed, use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to create a new searchable page. Views has the "**Expose**", which allow user to change them. All you have to do in View, is to add the "**Taxonomy term: Name**" on "**Sort Criteria**" and check the "**Expose this sort to visitor, to allow them to change it**". See below screenshot for details.
[image]